# Fast way to find index of array in array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, search, numpy, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have a numpy array of arrays of length 4:

```
In [41]: arr
Out[41]:
array([[  1,  15,   0,   0],
       [ 30,  10,   0,   0],
       [ 30,  20,   0,   0],
       ...,
       [104, 139, 146,  75],
       [  9,  11, 146,  74],
       [  9, 138, 146,  75]], dtype=uint8)
```

I want to know:

1. Is it true that `arr` includes `[1, 2, 3, 4]`?
2. If it true what index of `[1, 2, 3, 4]` in `arr`?

I want to find out it as fast as it possible.

Suppose `arr` contains 8550420 elements. I've checked several methods with `timeit`:

1. Just for checking without getting index: `any(all([1, 2, 3, 4] == elt) for elt in arr)`. It tooks 15.5 sec in average on 10 runs on my machine
2. `for`-based solution:

   `for i,e in enumerate(arr):
   if list(e) == [1, 2, 3, 4]:
     break`

   It tooks about 5.7 secs in average

Does exists some faster solutions, for example numpy based?

Comment: if you're not concerned about extra memory you could create dictionary where keys are tuples created from your lists

Comment: But will it save some time? It will take time to make dictionary of tuples from my array.

Comment: well it depends, if you perform your search more than once, than it definitely will save you some time

Comment: I think this answer might help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17797247/2452770. Using `where` in conjunction with `all` is probably what gives you the fastest find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [Jaime's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16216866/190597), I just love it:

```
import numpy as np

def asvoid(arr):
    """View the array as dtype np.void (bytes)
    This collapses ND-arrays to 1D-arrays, so you can perform 1D operations on them.
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/16216866/190597 (Jaime)"""    
    arr = np.ascontiguousarray(arr)
    return arr.view(np.dtype((np.void, arr.dtype.itemsize * arr.shape[-1])))

def find_index(arr, x):
    arr_as1d = asvoid(arr)
    x = asvoid(x)
    return np.nonzero(arr_as1d == x)[0]


arr = np.array([[  1,  15,   0,   0],
                [ 30,  10,   0,   0],
                [ 30,  20,   0,   0],
                [1, 2, 3, 4],
                [104, 139, 146,  75],
                [  9,  11, 146,  74],
                [  9, 138, 146,  75]], dtype='uint8')

arr = np.tile(arr,(1221488,1))
x = np.array([1,2,3,4], dtype='uint8')

print(find_index(arr, x))
```

yields

```
[      3      10      17 ..., 8550398 8550405 8550412]
```

---

The idea is to view each *row* of the array as a string. For example,

```
In [15]: x
Out[15]: 
array([^A^B^C^D], 
      dtype='|V4')
```

The strings look like garbage, but they are really just the underlying data in each row viewed as bytes. You can then compare `arr_as1d == x` to find which *rows* equal `x`.

---

[There is another way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17797247/190597) to do it:

```
def find_index2(arr, x):
    return np.where((arr == x).all(axis=1))[0]
```

but it turns out to be not as fast:

```
In [34]: %timeit find_index(arr, x)
1 loops, best of 3: 209 ms per loop

In [35]: %timeit find_index2(arr, x)
1 loops, best of 3: 370 ms per loop
```

Comment: I don't love it. Views can be a very nice trick, but you have to be careful about contiguiuty and if you use this on a float array you get `-0. != 0.` (does not matter for these uint8, but...). Is this even any faster then just using `arr.all` for each row? The view trick makes more sense to me if you want to use sorting methods because you need to find the index often.

Comment: Well, loving is perhaps too strong a word, but it seems to fill a need for which there is sometimes no other option. And in this case, it is faster than `np.all(..., axis=1)`.

Comment: Sorry, there is a ascontiguous array in there anyway, so that part is fine :)

Comment: No, you were correct; I just added it. And thanks for the warning regarding `-0. != 0.`

Answer (score 0):

If you perform search more than one time and you don't mind to use extra memory, you can create set from you array (I'm using list here, but it's almost the same code):

```
>>> elem = [1, 2, 3, 4]    
>>> elements = [[  1,  15,   0,   0], [ 30,  10,   0,   0], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> index = set([tuple(x) for x in elements])
>>> True if tuple(elem) in index else False
True
```

Comment: Don't even need the conditional statement. `tuple(... index` should be fine on itself. ( I can't check though; on my phone)